# Adding $3\cos\left(\sqrt{10}t + \frac\pi5\right) + 4\cos\left(4t+\frac\pi8\right)$ in order to find the period of the sum

Tags: trigonometry

(I had asked [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4200513/409) how should I begin to add together these two trigonometric functions: $z(t) = 3\cos(3t + \pi/5) + 4\cos(4t+\pi/8)$, in order to obtain the period of their sum). Now, I wonder how I might do so, should the angular frequency of the first be altered from $3$ to $\sqrt{10}$:
$$z(t) = 3\cos\left(\sqrt{10}t + \frac\pi5\right) + 4\cos\left(4t+\frac\pi8\right)$$

which I think to be considerably more difficult, for obeys no longer the relation $z(t+2π) = z(t)$.

[image]

Comment: The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4200532/291201) is the same, just with $\sqrt{10}$ instead of $3$. One difference is that the function is no longer periodic, but periodicity was nowhere used or assumed in that answer.

Comment: I do still think the resultant function to be periodic; and I have plotted it on Desmos to confirm it.

Comment: What do you think the period could be? It's not, see [Period of sum of sinusoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661638/period-of-sum-of-sinusoids) for example.

Comment: I think it periodic for no better reason than that is is formed of the sum of two periodic functions; and that the graph of it shows a regular pattern, which repeats itself again every $~7.754+0.13 = 7.88$s. (But as to how I should have obtained this number algebraically, I know not...)

Comment: Trust the math more than your eyes ;-) A linear combination $\cos(at)+\cos(bt)$ is periodic iff $a/b \in \mathbb Q$, and the same applies to your function $-$ but $\sqrt{10}/4 \not\in\mathbb Q$. You cannot reliably tell periodicity from a graph, any more than you can tell whether a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) is mathematically closed on the oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ T$ be the period
then $z(t+T)=z(t)$
$$3\cos(\sqrt{10}t+\frac{\pi}{5}+\sqrt{10}T)+4\cos(4t+\frac{\pi}{8}+4T)=3\cos(\sqrt{10}t+\frac{\pi}{5})+4\cos(4t+\frac{\pi}{8})$$

 $\exists p,m $ all integers such that 
$\sqrt{10}T=2\pi p,4T=2\pi m$

$$ \sqrt{10}T=\frac{4T}{m}p$$
$$\sqrt{10}=\frac{4}{m}p$$
so $\sqrt{10}$ is rational number impossible

the giving function has no period

Answer (score 3):

The given function
$z(t) = 3\cos\left(\sqrt{10}t + \frac\pi5\right) + 4\cos\left(4t+\frac\pi8\right)$
is not a periodic function!

If $L > 0$ is a period of $z$, then $L$ is a period of $z'' + \alpha^2 z$ for any $\alpha$. In particular, if one set $\alpha$ to $\sqrt{10}$ and $4$, one find $L$ is a period of

$$z'' + 10z = -24\cos(4t + \frac{\pi}{8})
\quad\text{ and }\quad
z'' + 16z = 18\cos(\sqrt{10}t+ \frac{\pi}{5})$$
This forces $L$ to be integer multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}}$ and as a corollary, $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4} = \frac{2\pi}{4} / \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{10}}$ is rational. Since this isn't the case, $L$ doesn't exist and $z$ is not periodic.